# How to handle the onClick function after its been clicked

Tags: reactjs, onclick

Ive created a expandList variable to show a list on click. After the click happens it shows the list but i am unable to close it.

```
const ExpandList = ({ students }) => {

    const { grades }  = students;
    const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

    

    function HandleClick(index) {
        if (isExpanded === index) {
            return setIsExpanded(null);
        }
        setIsExpanded(index);
    }

    return (
        <div className="grades">
            <button onClick={HandleClick}>
                { isExpanded ? <ImMinus/> : <ImPlus/> }
            </button>
            {isExpanded ? (
                <div className="grades">
                    {grades.map((grade, index) => 
                        <ul key={index}>Test {index + 1}: {grade}%</ul>)}
                </div>
            ) : null}
            
        </div>
    )
};
```

Not sure how to handle the HandleClick function after its been clicked.

Comment: Are you trying to toggle isExpanded ?

Comment: Yes that is my goal.

Comment: I hope I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to toggle isExpanded is to take the inverse value of isExpanded

You can achieve this like this :

```
 function HandleClick(){
   setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
 }
```

> Now every time you click on the button, the method will change the state of isExpanded to its inverse value

> **If the value is false it will change to true and so on**

---

Here is a documentation about the NOT operator
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT